# python psycopg logic error when inserting and retrieving from db

Tags: python, database, string, postgresql, psycopg3

tldr; Can someone explain how to optimally structure a psycopg INSERT statement using variables for the data being entered?

I am attempting to store basic data types into a PostgreSQL database using psycopg. The first block of code is my attempt to store values into the `ideatest` database, and the `ideastorage` table. The second block of code was written to retrieve everything currently in the `ideastorage` table.

I return no syntax errors when executing the first block, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work. The variables have already been defined and tested, but I think the `%s` string reference is where my issues lie.

```
    with psycopg.connect('dbname=ideatest user=postgres password=password') as conn: 
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('''
                INSERT INTO ideastorage (given_idea_id, idea_designation, idea_summary, idea_creation_time)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)''',
                (ideaID, ideaName, ideaSummary, ideaTime)
            )
```

This second block returns 'None,' but I think that's because my insert syntax is incorrect.

```
     with psycopg.connect('dbname=ideaTest user=postgres password=password') as conn: 
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('''
                SELECT idea_designation, idea_summary, idea_creation_time
                FROM ideastorage
                ORDER BY idea_designation'''
            )
            cur.fetchall()
```

So, I think my error lies with how I'm inserting data into the table. I've checked the documentation [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html), but I believe the syntax for psycopg (I'm using psycopg3, technically) is different from the psycopg2 syntax - and even that syntax tells me my first block won't work. How should I properly write the first block to insert variables into the database? (I understand variables in python are basically just pointers).

Comment: The syntax looks correct for the `INSERT`. The context manager `with psycopg.connect( ... ` will `commit()` the transaction. You need to do something like `rs = cur.fetchall()` and then `return rs` somewhere.

Comment: Do blocks return things?  As far as I know functions return things, by using "return".  Blocks don't return things.

Comment: That is why I said 'return rs somewhere'. There is more to this code then what is being shown. It is up to the OP to decide where to deal with the results.